# How to resolve error "Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'."

Tags: gradle

I am trying to run the "Unciv" open-sourced project locally (https://github.com/yairm210/Unciv) but am having issues running the gradle script in my linux environment. I keep getting the same error every time I run `./gradlew desktop:dist`:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
```

build scan:
https://scans.gradle.com/s/kz5ucjlxw5hle

I've tried deleting my previous JDK installations and reinstalling through brew or vscode's recommended files but no matter which installation I download or delete it seems like gradle is being pointed to the wrong JDK. How can I change the ''jvmTarget'`?